# Sinusoidal speed variation on my 5G wireless network adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have a [TP-Link TL-WDN6200 wireless network adapter](https://www.amazon.in/TP-LINK-TL-WDN6200-Wireless-Dual-band-ECAHP-341157/dp/B00RFG7TAG). I use it on a Windows 8 computer. I connect it to an [ASUS RT-ACRH17 router](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07628HLTM) over the 5G channel.

When I try to copy **a single big file** from a NAS server within the same LAN. I witnessed below speed graph:

[image]

The sinusoidal shape looks like an electrical issue. But I am not sure.

Other equipments connecting to the same 5G router doesn't have such issue.
And I tried the TP-LINK card on other computer, there's no such issue, either.

Anyone could shed some light on it?

### ADD 1

The 5G channel number is 157.

The speed drops every 10 seconds or so. And when the drop happens, the router's 5G link LED stops blinking, which I think means there's no data transmitting to the router. If so, maybe the wireless stick stops working every 10 seconds.

### ADD 2

I tried another version of driver. It still shows the same speed graph.

I tried another brand wireless stick with *the same speed 866Mbps*. It shows the same speed graph, too.

**I tried another [TL-WDN5200H](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2017-new-TL-WDN5200H-USB-600Mbs-Wireless-network-card-Avoid-driving-2-4-5-8G-Dual/32792834791.html) stick which has *a lower speed 450Mbps*. The speed bumping disappeared. And the speed looks even a bit higher than the trouble one.**

Isn't it strange?

Answer (score 1):

It may be difficult to get a conclusive answer on this one, but I'd put my money on it being a hardware limitation or driver issue with the WIFI stick.  (It could also be a QoS limitation, but I'd expect that to affect other devices for download speeds as well)

Assuming the download is happening over TCP, if it was an electrical issue there would be packet loss, which would lead to a less regularly shaped pattern.

It would be useful if you could identify the frequency of your graph - but I expect it is not 50 or 60 times per second, making it unlikely to be mains voltage related.  Similarly, if it were an electric fence, it would be a sharp zap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added some more details.

Comment: Your added I fo definitely points to a USB stick or driver issue - this is not power related.

Comment: I will upgrade the driver tonight and see if it works.

Comment: I updated with some new findings.